# Node.js chat server running on "cloud9-ide" is listening but not able to connect using client

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide

Chat server is listening to the port, below snippet is from console log.

```
Your code is running at https://mynodetest-someone.c9.io.
Important: use process.env.PORT as the port and process.env.IP as the host in your scripts!

debugger listening on port 15454
   info  - socket.io started
Chat server listening at 0.0.0.0:4000
```

When trying to connect through browser: eg: "localhost:4000", connection is refused(*Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)*

Can some one help how to fix this issue?.

Note:
I have tried listening on "127.0.0.1" and given original IP address in the network.

Comment: have you tried `https://mynodetest-someone.c9.io:4000` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the server using the URL that cloud9 provides for that specific server/project.

Use `process.env.PORT` as the port and `process.env.IP` as the host for you application and access your app using your project name - username. Should be something like `https://mynodetest-someone.c9.io`.

From the c9 page:

`Important: use process.env.PORT as the port and process.env.IP as the host in your scripts!`

Comment: Now it is working successfully. Thank you updating the important of "process.env.PORT" usage.